# CREATE MASTER KEY - Password validation failed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, password-encryption, encryption-asymmetric, sql-server-2012-express

logged in as 'sa' in MS sql server management studio, when I try

```
execute as login='sa'
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'S0URCE_DB KEY Pa$$W0rd'
```

it always takes more than 1 minute to get this error message, whatever kind of password I use.
password enforcement Policy is unchecked for login sa.

this is obviously not corresponding to the real error but have no clues what so ever it is.
could it be some Windows issue?
please help

```
Msg 15119, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Échec de la validation de mot de passe. Ce mot de passe ne répond pas aux exigences de la DLL de filtre de mots de passe.
```

English translation: `Password validation failed. The password does not meet the requirements of the password filter DLL.`

print @@version

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64) 
    Dec 28 2012 20:23:12 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your password policies are not the problem, it must be the other option: a password filter. Check with your administrator if he has installed such for security reasons: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721766.aspx